# Where is python folder? Python install problems

Tags: python, installation

I have installed Python 3.5.2 on my windows 8 computer, I tried in cmd `python --version` and it gave me that stupid error:

"python is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

I also have no files named python on my computer anywhere. I used the search feature on file explorer and I've search manually. I even looked through the hidden files. I have tried to install Python 3 times and the same thing keeps happening. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to install Python? Can you search for anything called 'IDLE'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 8 for Python 3.* I believe it is:
C:\Users\*yourusername*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\

To use that from the Windows command line you will need to add it to your path.

Control Panel -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Path

Add in the Python path at the end after a semi-colon, do not delete the others.

Comment: Thanks! this worked, I found my python was installed in C:\User\myusername\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\  How this happened I have no idea because this was not the installation path I selected. But I just copied that path to system variables and it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `which python` to find out the location of python in your computer. If it doesn't work and you cannot find where is the your installed directory, you may need to reinstall and make sure you remember the installation directory and add it as a environment variable in windows system.

Comment: This will only work on Linux systems, as Windows does not have `which`. `where` is the (almost) equivalent Windows command.

Answer (score 0):

I was probably same problem with python launcher.

In registry by **regedit** change
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command` from `"C:\some\path\to\python" "%1" %*` to `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`.

And first line of script shoud be:

```
#! python3
```

Now it shoud work properly and run in cmd just by `scriptname`, not `scriptname.py`, and not `py scripname.py`.